# Batch processing with Nvidia's TensorRT

Tags: pycuda, tensorrt

I converted the trained model to onnx format, and then created the TensorRT engine file from onnx model. I used the below snnipet code for doing this?

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
import tensorrt as trt

# logger to capture errors, warnings, and other information during the build and inference phases
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger()

def build_engine(onnx_file_path):
    # initialize TensorRT engine and parse ONNX model
    builder = trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER)
    network = builder.create_network()
    parser = trt.OnnxParser(network, TRT_LOGGER)
    
    # parse ONNX
    with open(onnx_file_path, 'rb') as model:
        print('Beginning ONNX file parsing')
        parser.parse(model.read())
    print('Completed parsing of ONNX file')
# allow TensorRT to use up to 1GB of GPU memory for tactic selection
builder.max_workspace_size = 1 << 30
# we have only one image in batch
builder.max_batch_size = 1
# use FP16 mode if possible
if builder.platform_has_fast_fp16:
    builder.fp16_mode = True
# generate TensorRT engine optimized for the target platform
    print('Building an engine...')
    engine = builder.build_cuda_engine(network)
    context = engine.create_execution_context()
    print("Completed creating Engine")

    return engine, context

# get sizes of input and output and allocate memory required for input data and for output data
for binding in engine:
    if engine.binding_is_input(binding):  # we expect only one input
        input_shape = engine.get_binding_shape(binding)
        input_size = trt.volume(input_shape) * engine.max_batch_size * np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize  # in bytes
        device_input = cuda.mem_alloc(input_size)
    else:  # and one output
        output_shape = engine.get_binding_shape(binding)
        # create page-locked memory buffers (i.e. won't be swapped to disk)
        host_output = cuda.pagelocked_empty(trt.volume(output_shape) * engine.max_batch_size, dtype=np.float32)
        device_output = cuda.mem_alloc(host_output.nbytes)

stream = cuda.Stream()

# preprocess input data
 host_input = np.array(preprocess_image("turkish_coffee.jpg").numpy(), dtype=np.float32, order='C')
 cuda.memcpy_htod_async(device_input, host_input, stream)

# run inference
    context.execute_async(bindings=[int(device_input), int(device_output)], stream_handle=stream.handle)
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(host_output, device_output, stream)
    stream.synchronize()

# postprocess results
    output_data = torch.Tensor(host_output).reshape(engine.max_batch_size, output_shape[0])
    postprocess(output_data)
```

The above codes is correctly work for one batch size of image, but I want to do for multi batch size, for this one thing that need to change :

```
builder.max_batch_size = 1
```

and What are other things I have to change to work correctly for batch size more than one? In my opinion, the one things that I have to change from sync to async, right?:

```
stream.synchronize()
```

How I can to solve the problem for batch size more than one?

**My system:**

torch:1.2.0
torchvision:0.4.0
albumentations:0.4.5
onnx:1.4.1
opencv-python:4.2.0.34
cuda:10.0
ubuntu:18.04
tensorrt: 5.x/6.x

Other solution is to use optimization profiler in TRT 7.x , But I want to know How I can to solve this problem with 5/6 versions, Is it possible?